# Not able to patch/mock instance functions which called from one of instance function on which I am writing unit test case

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have module `billing/billing-collect-project-license` which have `LicenseStatistics` class. Which have calls to Redis, ORMRDS, CE are other modules which used in this class. Following is `LicenseStatistics` class where `get_allocate_count` is instance method which calls to `ce_obj.get_set_ce_obj`, `get_license_id` and many others.

The `get_license_id` method calls `get_customer_details`.

```
class LicenseStatistics():
"""This class encapsulates all logic related to license usage."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = LOGGER

        # RedisNode List should be in the following format:
        #   HOST1:PORT1,HOST2:PORT2,HOST3:PORT3 etc
        redis_node_list = os.environ.get('REDIS_NODE_LIST', '').split(',')
        self.redis_utils = RedisUtils(redis_node_list)

        # DB object to read customer details
        dbhost = os.environ.get('DBHOST')
        dbuser = os.environ.get('DBUSER')
        dbpass = os.environ.get('DBPASSWORD')
        dbname = os.environ.get('DBNAME')
        dbport = os.environ.get('DBPORT')
        self.dbutils = ORMDBUtils(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname, dbport)
        self.ce_obj = CE()
        self.bill = Billing()

    def get_license_id(self, project_id):
        """
        @Summary: Get License Id for customer/project from customer table by
        project id
        @param project_id (string): CE project Id
        @return (string): CE License Id which associate with Project.
        """
        # Get license ID from RDS
        customer_details = self.get_customer_details(project_id)
        print("customer_details:", customer_details)
        license_id = customer_details["license_id"]
        if not license_id:
            msg = "No license for project {}".format(project_id)
            self.logger.error(msg)
            raise InvalidParamException(msg)

        print("license_id:", license_id)
        return  license_id

    def get_customer_details(self, project_id):
        """
        @Summary: Get Customer/Project details from customer table
        @param project_id (string): CE project Id
        @return (dictionary): Customer details from customer table.
        """
        filters = {"project_id": project_id}
        customer_details = self.dbutils.get_items(
            table_name=RDSCustomerTable.TABLE_NAME.value,
            columns_to_select=["account_id", "license_id"],
            filters=filters
        )
        if not customer_details:
            msg = "No customer found for project {}".format(project_id)
            self.logger.error(msg)
            raise NoCustomerException(msg)

        return customer_details[0]

    def is_shared_license(self, license_id):

        # This function return True or False  
        pass

    def get_project_machines_count(self, project_id, license_id):
        # This function return number of used license.
        count = 20
        return count

    def get_license_usage(self, project_id, license_id):
        # This function return number of machines used project.
        count = 10
        return count

    def get_allocate_count(self, project_id):
        """
        @Summary: Get number of licenses are used by Project.
        @param project_id (string): CloudEndure Project Id.
        @return (int): Number of license are used in Project.
        """
        # set Session get_customer_detailsfrom Redis
        status = self.ce_obj.get_set_ce_obj(
            project_id=project_id, redis_utils=self.redis_utils
        )
        print("license_id status--:", status)
        if not status:
            msg = "Unable to set CEproject {}".format(project_id)
            self.logger.critical(msg)
            raise InvalidParamException(msg, "project_id", project_id)

        print("project_id------------:", project_id)
        # Get license Id
        license_id = self.get_license_id(project_id)
        print("license_id:", license_id)
        # Check license is shared
        shared_flag = self.is_shared_license(license_id)
        if not shared_flag:
            # Get license usage
            licenses_used = self.get_license_usage(project_id, license_id)
        else:
            # Get machine account
            licenses_used = self.get_project_machines_count(
                project_id, license_id
            )

        return licenses_used
```

I am writing unit test for `get_allocate_count` method, I mock the Redis, ORMRDS, Custom Exception, Logger.
This function call  `ce_obj.get_set_ce_obj` function which return `True/False`. I am to mock/patch return value of this function successfully.
But when call goes to next function call i.e. `get_license_id`, call goes into actual function call and due to improper inputs. I am not able to patch/mock

Following is unit test code:

```
import responses
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import os
import sys

cwd_path = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd_path)

sys.path.append(cwd_path+"/../sam-cfns/code")
sys.path.append(cwd_path+"/../sam-cfns/code/billing")

from unit_tests.common.mocks.env_mock import ENV_VAR
from unit_tests.common.mocks.logger import FakeLogger
from unit_tests.common.mocks.cache_mock import RedisUtilsMock
from unit_tests.common.mocks.ormdb_mock import ORMDBUtilsMockProject
from unit_tests.common.mocks.exceptions_mock import NoCustomerExceptionMock
from unit_tests.common.mocks.exceptions_mock import BillingExceptionMock
from unit_tests.common.mocks.exceptions_mock import InvalidParamExceptionMock
from unit_tests.common.mocks.api_responses import mock_response
from unit_tests.common.examples import ce_machines_data
from unit_tests.common.examples import ce_license_data
from unit_tests.common.examples import ce_data


class BillingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Billing TEST class drive from UnitTest """

    @patch("billing-collect-project-license.Logger", FakeLogger)
    @patch("os.environ", ENV_VAR)
    @patch("billing-collect-project-license.RedisUtils", RedisUtilsMock)
    @patch("billing-collect-project-license.ORMDBUtils", ORMDBUtilsMockProject)
    @patch("exceptions.NoCustomerException", NoCustomerExceptionMock)
    @patch("billing.billing_exceptions.BillingException", BillingExceptionMock)
    @patch("billing.billing_exceptions.InvalidParamException", InvalidParamExceptionMock)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialization"""
        super(BillingTest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        billing_collect_project_license_module = (
            __import__("cbr-billing-collect-project-license")
        )
        self.licenses_stats_obj = (
            billing_collect_project_license_module.LicenseStatistics()
        )

class BillingCollectProjectLicense(BillingTest):
    """Login Unit Test Cases"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialization"""
        super(BillingCollectProjectLicense, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        """Setup for all Test Cases."""
        pass


    #@patch("billing.cbr-billing-collect-project-license.LicenseStatistics."
    #       "get_project_machines_count")
    #@patch("billing.cbr-billing-collect-project-license.LicenseStatistics."
    #       "get_customer_details")
    #@patch("billing.cbr-billing-collect-project-license.LicenseStatistics.get_license_id")
    @patch("billing.cbr-billing-collect-project-license.LicenseStatistics.get_license_id")
    @patch("cbr.ce.CloudEndure.get_set_ce_obj")
    def test_get_allocate_count(self, get_set_ce_obj_mock, get_license_id_mock):
        project_id = ce_data.CE_PROJECT_ID
        license_id = ce_license_data.LICENSE_ID
        get_set_ce_obj_mock.return_value = True
        get_license_id_mock.return_value = license_id
      # LicenseStatistics_mock.return_value.get_license_id.return_value = license_id
        #get_license_id_mock.return_value = license_id
       # self.licenses_stats_obj.get_license_id = get_license_id_mock
        get_customer_details_mock = {"license_id": license_id}
     #   is_shared_license_mock.return_value = True
     #   get_project_machines_count_mock.return_value = 20

        resp = self.licenses_stats_obj.get_allocate_count(
            project_id
        )
        self.assertEqual(resp, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am not able to patch `get_license_id` function from same class. This actually calling `get_license_id` function and fails. 
I want to mock return value of `get_license_id` function.

Anyone help help me?
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't try the code out, but it seems to me that the monkeypatching issue is with the `self.licenses_stats_obj`. You are initializing it in the `__init__`, so monkeypatching methods of `LicenseStatistics` class later have no effect on the already created instance. If you create the instance inside the test case, it should work fine as the monkeypatching itself looks good to me. BTW `@patch("billing.cbr-billing-collect-project-license.LicenseStatistics` - I doubt this will import at all since `cbr-billing-collect-project-license` is not a valid module name in Python.

Comment: @hoefling: You are initializing it in the __init__, so monkeypatching methods of LicenseStatistics class later have no effect on the already created instance,
yes I am also thinking same.

I doubt this will import at all since cbr-billing-collect-project-license is not a valid module name in Python:
>> this is valid module. I have some files which name contain hyphen. I know this should be underscore, but they are existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is I am   initializing it in the **init**, so monkeypatching methods of LicenseStatistics class later have no effect on the already created instance. @hoefling

By monkey Patching I able to run Test Cases successfully.

sample code:

```
def test_get_allocate_count_ok_4(self, ):
    """
    @Summary: Test case for successful response for shared license
    by other unittest method - Monkey Patching
    """
    def get_customer_details_mp(_):
        """Monkey Patching function for get_customer_details"""
        data = [
            {
                "account_id": "abc",
                "project_id": "abc",
                "license_id": "abc",
                "status": "Active"
            }
        ]
        return data
    def get_set_ce_obj_mp(_, _tmp):
        """Monkey Patching function for get_set_ce_obj"""
        return True
    def get_license_id_mp(_):
        """Monkey Patching function for get_license_id"""
        return "abc"
    def is_shared_license_mp(_):
        """Monkey Patching function for is_shared_license"""
        return True
    def get_project_machines_count_mp(_, _license_id):
        """Monkey Patching function for get_project_machines_count"""
        return 5

    project_id = "abc"

    # Monkey Patching
    self.licenses_stats_obj.get_customer_details = get_customer_details_mp
    self.licenses_stats_obj.ce_obj.get_set_ce_obj = get_set_ce_obj_mp
    self.licenses_stats_obj.get_license_id = get_license_id_mp
    self.licenses_stats_obj.is_shared_license = is_shared_license_mp
    self.licenses_stats_obj.get_project_machines_count = (
        get_project_machines_count_mp
    )

    resp = self.licenses_stats_obj.get_allocate_count(project_id)
    self.assertEqual(resp, 5)
```